# Dividing 2 input values in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a form that will calculate average pay. Very simply the calculation needs to be x/y = z. I would like it to autocomplete and not need to submit a form. This is what I have so far, I got close but I am going to insert the code onto a Weebly website and it could not read it. Any help would be massively appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(output1)
{
    var result = (input1/input2);
    document.getElementById("output1").value = result;
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body                    { font-family:Cambria; font-size:18px; line-height:28px; margin:0; padding:0;}
.container              
input                   { border:1px solid #eee; }
.container p label      { width:180px; float:left; }
p                       { clear:both; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form name="day calculator" method="post" action="">
<div class="container">
<p><font color="black"><b><label>Weekly Pay : </label></b><input type="number" name="input1" value=""/></p>
    <p><font color="black"><b><label>Days Worked : </label></b><input type="number" name="input2" value="" onBlur="calculate(this.value);"/></p>
    <p><font color="red"><b><label>Average Pay : </label><input type="number" name="output1" id="output1"></b></p>
</div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp here you can find all the events. I would use onChange on both inputs.

Comment: Thank you,I've added that and no error message now but still doesn't do the sum. I wonder if the issue is in the script section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. There are a number of issues here.
First, your javascript is referring to the HTML element, not it's value.
you need to add ids to the inputs and ensure that you convert the values to numbers.

This might help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate()
{
    var input1Val = Number(document.getElementById("input1").value);
    var input2Val = Number(document.getElementById("input2").value);
    var result = (input1Val/input2Val);
    document.getElementById("output1").value = result; 
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body                    { font-family:Cambria; font-size:18px; line-height:28px; margin:0; padding:0;}
.container              
input                   { border:1px solid #eee; }
.container p label      { width:180px; float:left; }
p                       { clear:both; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form name="day calculator" method="post" action="">
<div class="container">
<p><font color="black"><b><label>Weekly Pay : </label></b><input type="number" id="input1" name="input1" value=""/></p>
    <p><font color="black"><b><label>Days Worked : </label></b><input type="number" id="input2" name="input2" value=""/></p>
    <p><font color="red"><b><label>Average Pay : </label><input type="number" name="output1" id="output1"></b></p>
    <input type="button" value="Go!" onclick="calculate()">
</div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Even added a Go button too. The ids I think was something I hadn't come across but makes a lot of sense now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work. You have to watch out the difference to understand the problem in your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(input2)
{
 var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var result = (input1/input2);
    document.getElementById("output1").value = result;
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body                    { font-family:Cambria; font-size:18px; line-height:28px; margin:0; padding:0;}
.container              
input                   { border:1px solid #eee; }
.container p label      { width:180px; float:left; }
p                       { clear:both; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form name="day calculator" method="post" action="">
<div class="container">
<p><font color="black"><b><label>Weekly Pay : </label></b><input type="number" id="input1" name="input1" value=""/></p>
    <p><font color="black"><b><label>Days Worked : </label></b><input type="number" name="input2" value="" onBlur="calculate(this.value);"/></p>
    <p><font color="red"><b><label>Average Pay : </label><input type="number" name="output1" id="output1"></b></p>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```